# <Selenium WebDriver JS> Can't find element & implicit wait problems

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to write a Selenium script in JavaScript that will fill out an 'email' field on my site, but it keeps telling me "element not found"...

I'm trying to find this element:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control sweep" data-radium="true" data-reactid=".btcvpfkiyo.0.$/=10=22.0.0.$=12.0.0.0.$=10.$=11.0.$/=10.$=10.0" disabled="">
```

First I go to the page, then I wait for a few seconds before I try to find the element:

```
driver.get('www.mysite.com').then(function() {
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
driver.findElement({name:'email'})
    .then(function(present) {
        if (present) {
            console.log("Found");
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried to access this element in many ways... Here's what I've tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']"))
driver.findElement(By.css("input[type='email']"))
driver.findElement(By.css("input[name='email']"))
driver.findElement({name:'email'})
```

Every one of these gives me the same error: `no such element`

What's weird is that when I use jquery to select the element using js tools, it finds the element immediately. Every command above was tested in jquery and worked

I'm thinking the error could be one of these:

- Maybe my implicit wait isn't working (it does wait 10 seconds but I'm
  not sure if it's trying to find the element immediately). I also tried `implicitlyWait(10000).then` but maybe I did it wrong
- Maybe my selector is wrong

**Environment**

- **Selenium Webdriver v3.0.0-beta-2**

  - I'm using webdriver from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium.
  - The API is here: [Selenium Webdriver API](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#findElement)
- **Node v4.4.4**

Comment: There may be `frame/iframe` present, need to verify it, if desired element present inside any `frame/iframe` you need to switch that before finding element. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've tried all possible ways to find element, but you didn't look for `frame/iframe`.

There possibility to desired element present inside any `frame/iframe`.

If there `frame/iframe` exists you need to switch that `frame/iframe` using [`WebDriver#switchTo()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_TargetLocator.html) before finding desired element as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame/iframe id or name")

//Now find desire element inside frame/iframe

//After doing all stuff inside frame/iframe switch back to default content 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```